# Spring Controller is not invoked from jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement forgotpassword functionality for my application.

Before Logging in, if the user forgets the password he can recover. The recoverPassword jsp file reads the email ID and sends password to the emailID.

**My forgotPassword spring Controller is not getting invoked from JSP file, Whenever the user clicks on Recover Button login.jsp file is getting loaded again.**

We are using Spring Security 3.0
I added ForgotPassword Hyperlink on my login Page which opens a JSP file.

**recoverPass.jsp**

```
<form name="f" action="<c:url value="/all/recoveryPassword/pass" />" method="post">
        <div class="row clear">
            <div class="value">Enter your email:</div>
            <div class="parameter">
                <input type="text" name="email"/>
            </div>
            <div style="color: #FF0000;">${message}</div>
        </div>

        <br/>

        <div class="submit"><input type="submit" name="Recover" value="Recover"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <a href="<c:url value="/jsp/login.jsp" />">Log In</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**RecoverPasswordController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/recoveryPassword")
public class RecoveryPasswordController  extends BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO usersDao;    

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pass", method =RequestMethod.POST)
    public String recoverPassword(@RequestParam("json") String json, ModelMap model){
       //Code to read the email ID check DB and send a new password in email         
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {            
            model.addAttribute("error", true);
            return "d"; 
        }       
        return "redirect:/recoveryPasswordSuccess";
    }
}
```

TO Exclude the Controller from Spring Security, I added the following in **applicationContext-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

      <http realm="Contacts Realm" use-expressions="true">
            <intercept-url pattern="/all/recoveryPassword/*" filters="none"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
    .....
```

and finally my **web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml,/WEB-INF/classes/remote-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/abc/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**Can Anyone please help me Resolve this issue, I have been trying to fix this problem from past 1 week.**

Comment: I'd recommend Firebug to verify that you're POSTing to where you expect... your `c:url` includes _/all/_, your controller annotation does not. By default, `c:url` will automatically include the context-root if that is your intention here.

Comment: Are you sure that your controller is picked up by Spring MVC during sturtup (annotations are turned on, corresponding package is scanned)?  Unrelated: remove unused @RequestParam("json") String json

Comment: @Maksym Demidas -- Yes, I have added the new class under one of the root Package. Our Root package is com.myProject and this controller is under com.myProject.user.presentation. The following tag is present in remote-servlet.xml -- <context:component-scan base-package="com.myProject" />. 
I guess before authentication, spring security is not allowing jsp to access the controller.

Comment: @BeauGrantham - Yes /all/ is including context-root.
Our application used Ext-Js , Spring security. All ext-js files request controller through ajax calls. I tries adding a script in jsp file to make ajax call to the controller. This also didn't work.

Comment: Please show all your applicationContext-security.xml. Enable DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.security` package. May be there is somethinig interesting in the log during submit processing?

Comment: By default, c:url will automatically include the context-root if that is your intention here. – Beau Grantham .
This has done the trick. Now my controller is invoked. How can I mark your comment as Answer.Pls let me know, I am new to this forum.

Comment: The above Problem is fixed, Now I have a new problem. The Controller is invoked but we need to email the user his new Randomly generated password. We have a Class File which does this, we are using mail.jar to achieve this. The problem here is the file throws an exception at like `Transport.send(Msg)` . The Exception is **Access Denied** Exception. Do we have to exclude this class also from Spring security ?